# How can I add optional validation patten in preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm try to use `preg_match` to parse the line. But, couldn't get the result correctly.

I want to parse those lines with optional `//` char.

Basic idea is some lines may contain //0016OIXXXXXXX (//4 digit and 9 str) and some line may not contain (//4 digit and 9 str).

Next line `\n` is mandatory.

Here are some sample lines;

**Line 1**

`1812121212DD2220,31NTRFNONREF
502?102330`

**Line 2**

`1811091109CD20693,12NTRFRMSOIC110871941//0016RFXXXXXXX
206?000801`

Here is my patten;

`/(\d{6})((\d{2})(\d{2}))?(C|D)([A-Z]?)([0-9,]{1,15})([A-Z]{1,4})([A-Z a-z 0-9]{1,16})(\/\/)([0-9A-Z]{1,16})(\s*\n)([0-9]{1,3})(\?)([0-9]{0,6})/`

Current patten can only work with `//`. If without `//`, patten is broken and can't parse the line.

I don't know how should I add `(\/\/)([0-9A-Z]{1,16})` as optional patten.

Thanks in advance
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the optional part well... optional:

```
\d{6}(?:\d{4})?[CD][A-Z]?[0-9,]{1,15}[A-Z]{1,4}[A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,16}(?:\/\/[0-9A-Z]{1,16})?\s*\n[0-9]{1,3}\?[0-9]{0,6}
//                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've removed the capture groups for lisibility, if you really want to keep them:

```
(\d{6})((\d{2})(\d{2}))?(C|D)([A-Z]?)([0-9,]{1,15})([A-Z]{1,4})([A-Za-z0-9 ]{1,16})(?:(\/\/)([0-9A-Z]{1,16}))?(\s*\n)([0-9]{1,3})(\?)([0-9]{0,6})
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/V8HTt6/1)

Comment: Thanks Toto. Will take a look again

Answer (score 1):

If Am I understanding right your question.

Please, try to use  `or` expression between the groups and validate any you case. 
For example

```
`(pattern1) | (pattern-2) | ( (pattern3) | (pattern 4)  )`
```

Please, try to consider using the `|` expression.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your answer. Working good. I forgot `|` option.